# FTS speed Mongo vs Lucene, is it misconfiguration, causing Lucene to be thousands times faster

Tags: java, mongodb, lucene

I have a collection in Mongo with around 60 mln organisations. Each having short and long name. I've setup text index on both fields with

```
db.orgs.createIndex( {"fullname": text, "shortname":text} )
```

Size of index is 2.4GB.

I've tried languages en and ru (in second case stemming works, but speed is the same).

The problem is SPEED!

I tried mongo shell and java driver.

```
db.orgs.find({ $text:{ $search: "blabla search" }},{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).pretty().sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).limit(10)

BasicDBObject score = new BasicDBObject("score", new BasicDBObject("$meta", "textScore"));
result = collEgrul.find(fuzzy).projection(score).sort(score).maxTime(request.getLimitTimeSec(), TimeUnit.SECONDS).limit(request.getLimitRecords()).batchSize(request.getLimitRecords())
```

It runs at least for 10 second for very rare word combinations. And it often runs for 50-100-200 seconds on common words. 
Judging to logs, it **does** do IXSCAN

Sooo... my question is - is it OK for Mongo? Server has 96GB and index is 100% sure warm and in RAM.

I've setup Lucene on same server and now get search speed of 10-100 **milliseconds**. But for the great justice would like to investigate the problem. Any clues?

Comment: I'm not a mongo expert but have done a small benchmark on it in the past and got absolutely disappointed with the query performance. What u say, aligns with what I saw at the time. Good luck with figuring out why it is slow! ;-)